# Sesquilinear Forms: Hamiltonian (II)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a positive form:
$$s:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad s(\varphi,\varphi)\geq0$$

Introduce its form space:
$$\mathcal{H}_s:=\mathcal{D}:\quad\langle\varphi,\psi\rangle_s:=s(\varphi,\psi)+\langle\varphi,\psi\rangle$$

Then it is closable:
$$s\subseteq\hat{s}:\iff\mathcal{H}_s\subseteq\mathcal{H}_\hat{s}:=\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s\subseteq\mathcal{H}$$

Is there a sophisticated way?

Comment: Perhaps you could spell out exactly what is meant by the display following "it is closable".  There are some subtle details in what the hat means and exactly what you mean by $\subseteq$.  I presume you are not claiming the form is always closable, but rather that it is closable iff something else happens.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oh I thought one can always close a form that is bounded below, isn't it? By closable I mean that its form space has a completion within the Hilbert space. Is that right?

Comment: No, that is false.  A standard counterexample is something like $\mathcal{H} = L^2([-1,1])$, $\mathcal{D} = C([-1,1])$ and $s(f,g) = f(0) \overline{g(0)}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Hmmm... But then there must be a flaw in the proof below?

Comment: You are tacitly assuming that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on the completion of $\mathcal{H}_s$ (which I assume is what you mean by $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s$).  A priori, an element of $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s$ is an equivalence class of $\|\cdot\|_s$-Cauchy sequences of elements of $\mathcal{H}_s \subset \mathcal{H}$.  These sequences are also $\|\cdot\|$-Cauchy, so they also converge in $\mathcal{H}$.  But Cauchy sequences that converge to the same thing in $\mathcal{H}$ may be inequivalent in $\|\cdot\|_s$-norm.

Comment: So there is a canonical map from $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s$ into $\mathcal{H}$, but it may not be injective.  As a result, $\|\cdot\|$ is not necessarily a norm on $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s$ but only a seminorm - there can be nonzero elements $\varphi$ of $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s$ with $\|\varphi\| = 0$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Hmm I see because only $\|\varphi\|\leq\|\varphi\|_s$. But what about my explicit construction of $\hat{\mathcal{H}_s}$?

Comment: I have a little trouble following your purported proof because it is not clear what spaces various elements lie in, nor how exactly you are defining $\hat{\mathcal{H}}_s$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Shall we continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23263/discussion-between-nate-eldredge-and-freeze-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the form is given by:
$$s(\varphi,\psi)=\langle A\varphi,\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi,A\psi\rangle$$

Regard the embedding:
$$\iota:\mathcal{H}_s\to\mathcal{H}:\varphi\mapsto\varphi$$

Clearly it is bounded:
$$\|\iota(\varphi)\|=\|\varphi\|\leq\|\varphi\|_s$$

So it extends to:
$$\hat{\iota}:\hat{\mathcal{H}_s}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad\|\hat{\iota}\|<\infty$$

By continuity one has:
$$\hat{\iota}(\varphi)=0:\quad\varphi_n\to\varphi\implies\hat{\iota}(\varphi_n)\to0$$

By density one can choose:
$$\varphi_n\in\mathcal{H}_s:\quad\hat{\iota}(\varphi_n)=\iota(\varphi_n)=\varphi_n$$

So it must vanish:
$$\|\varphi\|_s\leftarrow\langle\varphi,\varphi_n\rangle_s=\lim_m\{\langle \varphi_m,A\varphi_n\rangle+\langle\varphi_m,\varphi_n\rangle\}=0\to0$$

Thus it embeds.

Answer (score 0):

ATTENTION: THIS PROOF HAS A FLAW!!!

**Failure**

It is not guaranteed:
$$\|\varphi_m-\varphi_n\|_s\to0\nRightarrow\|\varphi-\varphi_n\|_\hat{s}\to0$$
So the norm is ill-defined.

**Proof**

It holds the estimate:
$$\|\varphi\|^2\leq s(\varphi,\varphi)+\|\varphi\|^2=\|\varphi\|_s$$

That offers explicitely:
$$\|\varphi_m-\varphi_n\|_s\to0\implies\|\varphi_m-\varphi_n\|\to0\implies\|\varphi-\varphi_n\|\to0$$

So complete it by:
$$\mathcal{H}_\hat{s}:\quad\langle\varphi,\psi\rangle_\hat{s}:=\lim_n\langle\varphi_n,\psi_n\rangle_s$$

That limit exists since:
$$0\leq|\langle\varphi_m,\psi_m\rangle_s-\langle\varphi_n,\psi_n\rangle_s|\leq\|\varphi_m-\varphi_n\|_s\|\psi_m\|_s+\|\varphi_n\|_s\|\psi_m-\psi_n\|_s\to0$$

And is well-defined since:
$$0\leq|\langle\varphi_n,\psi_n\rangle_s-\langle\tilde{\varphi}_n,\tilde{\psi}_n\rangle_s|\leq\|\varphi_n-\tilde{\varphi}_n\|_s\|\psi_n\|_s+\|\tilde{\varphi}_n\|_s\|\psi_n-\tilde{\psi}_n\|_s\to0$$

Noting the estimate:
$$0\leq\|\varphi_n-\tilde{\varphi}_n\|_s\leq\|\varphi-\varphi_n\|_s+\|\tilde{\varphi}-\tilde{\varphi}_n\|_s\to0$$

But algebraic properties remain:
$$\hat{s}(\varphi,\psi):=\langle\varphi,\psi\rangle_\hat{s}-\langle\varphi,\psi\rangle:\quad\hat{s}(\varphi,\varphi)=\|\varphi\|_\hat{s}^2-\|\varphi\|^2\geq0$$

So one obtains the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Consider the positive form:
$$s:\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R}):\quad s(\varphi,\psi):=\overline{\varphi(0)}\psi(0)$$

Regard a sequence of bumps:
$$\varphi_n\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}):\quad\varphi_n\left(|x|\geq\tfrac{2}{n}\right)\equiv0\leq\varphi_n\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\leq|x|\leq\frac{2}{n}\right)\leq1\equiv\varphi_n\left(|x|\leq\tfrac{1}{n}\right)$$

Contradictory one has:
$$\|\varphi_m-\varphi_n\|_s\to0\quad\|0-\varphi_n\|_s\not\to0$$

So the form is not closable!